# Are there any advantages to using higher priced sealers?

Tags: concrete, brick

I want to use a water based sealer on my pavers to bring out the color and also for some resistance against dirt and fading.  I went to the store and saw sealers varying in price from about $11 per gallon for Thompson's water seal to about $24 for a Behr brand low luster to sealer to over $30 for a natural stone and brick name-brand sealer.

Is there really much difference in quality and longevity to justify the higher prices of the mid and name-brand sealers?

Comment: I believe (at the end of the day), your question is off topic as it is going to force much opinion, at least based on how you asked it. At the end of the day, the price of a product does not ensure quality. A sleezy manufacturer could sell you close to water for $50 a gallon, and another could sell you a poly for $10. @Jeff below and others noted looking at the warranty and consider its longevity. You could also look at ease of application, and peoples comments on appearence. Look at users reviews in both good and bad and consider a mid range price point.

Comment: I agree with noybman. Price is not an indication of quality. However, different products certainly do offer more or less protection, durability, and beauty than others, and _in general_, price can help indicate which are more likely to be higher quality.

Answer (score 1):

Linseed Oil makes a great concrete sealer/sealant.
The only caution you should take is the applicator that you use. Make sure you submerse the applicator in water after completion. Linseed Oil is highly flammable.

https://www.doityourself.com/stry/using-boiled-linseed-oil-as-concrete-floor-sealant

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is - as is the quality in everything name brand and generic. 
One thing I have learned so far in life - if it is something important that you want to last, spend more money on it.
If you expect it to break / not last long. Spend less money on it.

With that being said, sometimes the price increases are related to the warranty associated with it.

**Sealers are basically priced based on how long is it going to last.**

Behr does not last the 4 years they promise.
Thompsons doesn't last a year in most cases.
CABOT is the the most recommended, if that is the $30 sealant you are speaking of.

Comment: While I generally agree with your sentiment, this answer could be improved by explaining what the differences in quality actually are.

Comment: There is nothing in your answer that addresses the OP's search for an answer specific to paver sealants.

Comment: I bet if OP reads the labels one has a longer warranty than the other.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of concretes sealers.  Most have certain qualities that would make them work better/worse depending on the amount of sun, temperature, moisture and other variables.  Your favorite sealer in Minnesota may be a terrible choice in Texas.  Do some research on what people are using in your area and for your type of application.  Paying extra for the "best" product is not as important is finding the right product for you.

Answer (score -1):

Personally i would recommend using [Waterglass](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QL4ZV0I). I'm not sure how long the shine would last of such a treatment, but it has proven effects on the durability in the realm of 20-30% longer life.

I suspect that most brand sealers are based on it but with a huge markup.

Comment: This is a product recommendation (which are off topic) and doesn't answer the fundamental question being posed.